# Coma in url after proxy with Apache

Tags: proxy, apache2, odoo

I'm using Apache to proxy all requests from my domain to my Odoo server.

Then to proxy all requests from my customers URLs to their respective databases (sub-domain of my domain).

Here's what my config looks like:

```
################
# welcome page #
################

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.fr
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.fr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/odoo
</VirtualHost>


#################
# wilcard proxy #
#################

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.fr
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.fr

    ErrorLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/odoo/odoo-access.log combined
    LogLevel warn

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://mydomain.fr:8089/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mydomain.fr:8089/

    ProxyVia On
</VirtualHost>


##################
# customer proxy #
##################

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName customer-domain.fr
    ServerAlias www.customer-domain.fr

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://customer-domain.mydomain.fr/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://customer-domain.mydomain.fr/

    ProxyVia On
</VirtualHost>


################
# restrictions #
################

<Location /web/database>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 1.2.3.4
    Allow from 5.6.7.8
</Location>
```

Now, when I go to `customer-domain.fr`, after I click a few internal links, I'm redirected to `customer-domain.fr, customer-domain.mydomain.fr`.

Which is weird, because it's as if Apache somehow appended the target URL at the end of the source url of the proxy. I tried with Chrome, Firefox, and someone else house.

What causes this coma to appear, and how to prevent this ?

---

**Update**

I commented out the `<Proxy *>` section.

So, I did some tests with the console:

- clear cache
- go to customer-domain.fr -> no problem here, I receive a 200 response on the exact domain I requested.
- click on English to change the language of the website : here are the headers :

  ```
  **General**
  Request URL:http://customer-domain.fr/website/lang/en_US?r=%2Fen_US%2Fpage%2Fhomepage
  Request Method:GET
  Status Code:303 SEE OTHER
  Remote Address:01.23.45.67:80

  **Response Headers**
  Connection:Keep-Alive
  Content-Encoding:gzip
  Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
  Date:Fri, 13 Jan 2017 13:53:21 GMT
  Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=100
  Location:http://customer-domain.fr, customer-domain.mydomain.fr/en_US/page/homepage
  Server:Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.3
  Set-Cookie:website_lang=en_US; Path=/
  Set-Cookie:session_id=xxx; expires=Thu, 13-Apr-2017 13:53:21 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/
  Transfer-Encoding:chunked
  Vary:Accept-Encoding
  Via:1.1 mydomain.fr
  Via:1.1 customer-domain.fr

  **Request Headers**
  Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
  Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
  Cache-Control:no-cache
  Connection:keep-alive
  Cookie:website_lang=fr_FR; session_id=xxx
  Host:customer-domain.fr
  Pragma:no-cache
  Referer:http://customer-domain.fr/
  Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36

  **Query String Parameters**
  r:/en_US/page/homepage
  ```

Comment: try installing mod_rewrite and add this directly under "ProxyRequest Off" - "RewriteEngine on"

Comment: also, this should be added right below ProxyPassReverse:
RewriteRule ^/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L,R=301]

Comment: I added that in the # wilcard proxy # section, but now I got a "Problem loading page"

Comment: I don't see how mod_rewrite is needed here and that rewrite may very well add a loop. I believe the key here is those links he clicks, exactly where do they point?, and the use of ProxyPreserveHost on. Also remove Proxy * entry if you don't want a forward proxy, as you seem you don't want when you are also using proxyrequests off. There is need for more specific detail here, and using mod_rewrite as a magic duct and tape recipe to workaround things is not the solution imho. Run away from mod_rewrite unless it is strictly necessary to use it.

Comment: Use the webconsole or a web browser or curl to know exactly when you get redirected like that, that detail is needed

Comment: Thanks for your help. The goal is to serve specific Odoo databases to customers URLs. However, Odoo is already configured to serve databases which match requested subdomains. That's why I need to do : some-customer-domain.com -> database.my-domain.com -> my-domain.com:8069 | The second proxy works really well. The first one is causing trouble. I'll add more details if I can get more informations with curl or something else.

Comment: Ok I've updated the answer